# Regex replace muliple linebreaks with <br> tag

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string as follows:

> \r\n  \r\n  Some text blahblah \r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n Some other text \r\n  \r\n
>   \r\n  \r\n blah blah blah \r\n

I want to replace any instances of multiple linebreak with just one `<br>` tag and also any single \r\n to a `<br>`

So the text above should look like this:

```
<br>  Some text blahblah <br><br> Some other text <br><br> blah blah blah <br>
```

I have tried this but it does not take into account the spaces between: \r\n  \r\n

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"[\r\n]+", "<br>")
```

Comment: Your example contradicts your description.  If you want to convert multiple linebreaks into a single `<br>`, why does your expected output have pairs of `<br>` in it?

Comment: Why would multiple `<br>`s remain in your output? What's the replacement logic?

Comment: var something = ...... ;

Comment: @Jon The logic is to preserve some of the original formatting.

Comment: @JCoder23: That's the *idea*, not the *logic* that implements it.

Comment: @JCoder23 I've modified my answer, does it do what you expecting?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should do the job

```
string myString = "\r\n \r\n Some text blahblah \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n Some other text \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n blah blah blah \r\n";
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"(?:\r\n *){1,2} *", "<br>");
```

will produce

```
<br>Some text blahblah <br><br>Some other text <br><br>blah blah blah <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this (not Regex, but works :) ), and this will support odd/even numbers of `\r\n` and will add tags to begining and end if `\r\n` is missing.

```
 var result = string.Concat(text.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' })
                .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
                .Select(s => string.Format("<br> {0} <br>",s)));
```

Result:

```
\r\n \r\n Some text blahblah \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n Some other text \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n blah blah blah \r\n
"<br> Some text blahblah <br><br> Some other text <br><br> blah blah blah <br>"

 \r\n \r\n Some text \r\n Some other \r\n \r\n \r\n  blah blah blah 
"<br> Some text <br><br> Some other <br><br> blah blah blah <br>"
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"([\r\n]\s*)+", "<br>")
```

Or this if you don't want it to consume the space after the run of line breaks:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"[\r\n](\s*[\r\n])+", "<br>")
```

Comment: \s is similar to [\r\n\t\f ]..it's better you use plain space instead of \s

Comment: That's a good point, but I'm assuming that consuming any whitespace between the line breaks would be desirable in this case. I've added an alternate answer that doesn't consume anything _after_ the run of line breaks.